# Install pywin32 package in google colab or kaggle notebook environment

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, pywin32, kaggle, winreg

pywin32 package was required to install as part of requirements to set up the environment for pix2pix implementation [codebase](https://github.com/mohaEs/image-to-images-translation), pywin32 is used to enable the features of the Win32 API in python. I tried to set up an environment in google colab, and produced the following error message during pywin32 setup.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32
> (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for
> pywin32

Similar issue with the following message encountered while trying to implement in kaggle:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32

The same issue encountered when I tried in my local python environment (Python 3.6.10) in my mac.

Also, I attempt to install pywin32 package from its [source](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/) itself, using the latest tag [build-300](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases/tag/b300) as suggested for python 3.5+. But no luck, installation terminated with the dependency issue with winreg package not found, following message was shown.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'

Likewise, tried with [fake-winreg](https://pypi.org/project/fake-winreg/), but no luck at all. I checked the platform in google colab by print(sys.platform), it shows linux. Please advise if there is any workaround to install pywin32 package in colab and/or resolution solving any issue reported in the above steps. Thank you in advance.

**Note:**
Issue can be replicated by simply try `pip install pywin32` in native python environment, and `!pip install pywin32` in colab or kaggle environment.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't install it in linux python, pywin32 is a package of extension modules for accessing Windows C and COM APIs in Windows python:

> Python extensions for Microsoft Windows Provides access to much of the Win32 API, the ability to create and use COM objects, and the Pythonwin environment.

**Google Colab**
[image]

**Kaggle**
[image]

Comment: Appreciate your follow-up response. However, pywin32 can't install in Linux python, is there any workaround worth trying the solution on top of wine or something similar in colab or kaggle environment?

Comment: There no support for Linux OS: https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files You could try running Python under Wine but I think it is not a solution for you.

Comment: Then, no luck for writing platform-independent code. 
@The 5th column mouse - Appreciate your response and the follow-up comment.